# Dont' Show HTML Buttons when i convert them to pdf online

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have a webpage which include some buttons, when i convert the HTML page to pdf, the button also come in pdf... i dont want the buttons to be shown in the buttons

Comment: I think it would be useful to have and dea on how your site converts to PDF libraries etc.

Comment: @Trufa, was it necessary to remove that?

Comment: @TylerCrompton: necessary, maybe not. But Im sure it is in the best interest of the OP, saying "please HELP" and those kind of expressions are generally trowed upon in SO.

Comment: i convert my html page to pdf from web2pdfconvert.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are printing to a PDF you can make a print stylesheet that goes something like
    `input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
        display: none;
    }`

Comment: things work fine if i directly print the html page... but if i convert the html page to pdf, display:none is not working there...

Comment: i have a link on the page.."Publish to pdf", after that using javascript the page is converted to pdf from Web2Pdfconvert.com

Comment: Hmm. I can't think of any reasonable way to do so like that. If you wanna rely on JS you can set the display to none by default and have javascript change the display to `inline`. Maybe that will work?

Comment: thanks, i got the answer in the javascript... i added display none to links and buttons, and it worked :D

Comment: No problem. Just be careful because users can turn off Javascript. And you can't use the `noscript` tags to turn on the display because that will most likely make the conversion show the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe use jquery to do something like the following below when the link "Publish to pdf is clicked" before the whole javascript processing is done to convert the html to pdf:

$(link).click(function(){
   $(this).css("display", "none"); 
});

NOTE: "link" above is the name of your link "Publish to pdf"

Comment: That won't work because the user will have to leave the page.